# How to stream system() command ouput to any variable

Tags: c, windows, stream

I created a C program which will run some `system()` commands and save the output to a `.txt` file in a particular folder of C drive (program is to be run on domain clients with startup privileges), from where I'll filter the data and show it on output console screen.

Everything worked fine, but I couldn't design it for those PCs who have OS installed in other drives (*e.g.* `D:`, `E:`, etc), since they will not have this particular folder in their `C:` drive. I can't write temporary `.txt` files anywhere else due to group policies.

Is there any method to stream this data directly into any array variable? I went through `popen()` function, but it would require a very large array of unpredicted size to be defined (since the output of `system()` command may be very large). For example, exporting the registry keys of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\uninstall` into a `.txt` file. Its size may be up to 50KB or bigger.

```
    reg export HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\uninstall C:\\..(somewhere)....\\reg_output.txt
```

There are some more similar commands with large output. I don't know Win API programming yet, thus I am using system command. Can there be an easy alternative to writing to `.txt` ?

---

@Megharaj!
As you used

```
    char line[100];
    fp = popen("ifconfig eth0", "r");
    fgets(line, 100, fp);
```

I'll have to use

```
    char reg_output[100000];
    fp=popen("reg export HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\uninstall ????","r");
    fgets(line,100000,fp);
```

Where do I export the registry values? (Since the DOS command for exporting this needs to write it to a file), as compared to following code I am using.

Assigning a space of 100000 isn't sure that it will not be error prone. And assigning too high value also will affect the memory on startup (I'm not sure but guess so).

While using file handling I do it as:

```
    char line[5000];   FILE* fp_reg;  int ch,n=0;
    system("reg export HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\uninstall c:\\registries.txt");
    fp_reg=fopen("c:\\registries.txt","r");
    while((ch=fgetc(fp_reg))!=EOF)
    {
        if(isalnum(ch) || ch=='\n')  //allow only alpha numeric & '\n' to pass to array
        { line[n]=ch;
          if(ch=='\n')
          {    filter_for_software(line,n);  //Send the array for filtering function
               n=0;   // Reset the array 'line'
          }
          n++;                
        }    
    }
```

(I didn't copy the code from source, since I am sitting on a different PC. But the code is almost similar to this. Some errors may come if you copy this code & run.)
This way, I take each line from file and send it for filtering to get 'installed software's name'. How do I do it with 'popen()', so that I could pick up a line and throw it onto a function. Plz write some code also for this.

Comment: I don't understand what problem you had with `popen`, which is the correct function to use. Yes, you may need a large array to store the result, but surely that would be the case no matter what method you used. You can also read the output in parts if you don't want to store it all.

Comment: He is using windows, no popen there as far as I know...

Comment: @interjay: The real problem with `popen` is that it doesn't help because `reg export` doesn't write it's output to `stdout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I prepared the code to stream the output of a DOS command to a file pointer in read mode and check it line by line:

```
    char array_sys[200];  FILE *fp_sys;   int ch,n=0;
    fp=popen("systeminfo","r");  //runs a DOS command & read it with a file pointer
    if(fp_sys==NULL)     printf("can't open file\n"); 
    while((ch=fgetc(fp_sys))!=EOF)  //READ CHARACTERS FROM FILE POINTER UNTIL FILE ENDS
    { 
            array_sys[n]=ch;     //ASSIGN CH TO EACH ELEMENT OF ARRAY    
            n++;                 //INCREMENT ELEMENTS OF ARRAY:-arr_sys
            if(ch=='\n')         //IF ELEMENTS MEET A NEW LINE CHARACTER
            { 
                    disp_date(array_sys,n);  //PASS ARRAY TO FUNCTION:-disp_date
                    n=0;                     //RESET THE ARRAY
            }   
    }
```

Now this is how I process array in function to get the name of operating system.

```
    void disp_date(char array_sys[],int ind)
    { 
       char os_name[9]={"OS Name:"};
       if(strstr(array_sys,os_name)) //IF 'OS NAME' IS PRESENT IN ARRAY
       {  
            printf("%s",array_sys);  //PRINT THE ARRAY
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In linux to use the values from the system command i use popen, I am just giving an example of code that I had written some time long back, to get the ip address of the pc by system command "ifconfig eth0" to the string/a file. see the example

```
    void get_my_ip(char *ip_mac_address)
{
    FILE *fp,*output;
    char *start=NULL; 
    char *end=NULL;
    char line[100];
    output=fopen("my_ip_address.txt", "w");
    if(output == NULL) {
        printf("error creating outputfile\n");
        return -1; 
    }

    printf("program to self query the ip address\n");   
    fp = popen("ifconfig eth0", "r");
    fgets(line, 100, fp);
    start=strstr(line, CHECK_STRING_MAC);
    start = start + 7;
    fwrite(start, 1, 17, output); start = NULL;
    fgets(line, 100, fp);
    start=strstr(line, CHECK_STRING_IP);
    start = start + 10;
    fwrite(start, 1, 14, output);
    fclose(output); 
    pclose(fp);
    if( access("my_ip_address.txt", F_OK ) != -1 ) {
        printf("found file having ip address\n");
        output=fopen("my_ip_address.txt", "r");
        fgets(ip_mac_address, 32, output);
    }
    else
        printf("unabe to find file with ip address\n");
    fclose(output);
    printf("my ip and mac address adress is %s \n",ip_mac_address);

}
```

Comment: I am not sure it's relevant, he said his output is too large.

Comment: @LtWorf ok, but will it be a problem if the entire output is taken into a file, than a buffer which reads each line. at least the buffer nedded to read each line will be short. correct me. also his heading is "How to stream system() command ouput to any variable" thats what exactly i am doing in my core. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LTWorf What's the difference between the output being too large in a pipe or in a temporary file? Processing it works much the same way.

Comment: Well yes he didn't say what kind of filter he needs, if they are grep-like then yes he can proceed line by line, but for example if he needs  something more complex he might need the entire thing in memory before he can proceed.
Also, he is asking about windows and you posted some POSIX C code.

Comment: @MikeHartl The difference is that a large file lives on disk, not in RAM.

Comment: @LtWorf Neither does it live in RAM with a pipe. Pipes have a [limited memory buffer](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/memory-usage-unix-pipe-help-173344831.html). If you don't read the output quick enough, then the writing process will just block and wait until there is space available. And, btw, 50kb in RAM wouldn't be a big problem either. ;-) Edit: MSDN also [confirms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with how a pipe works. Don't know, perhaps the poster doesn't know exactly what he's aiming for, to me it seems like he wants the entire output somewhere, to filter afterwards. But perhaps that's just a flaw in his design.

Comment: @MikeHartl yes. I agree. LTWorf sorry I am a linux guy, I don't know about windows.

Comment: Plz give me some time to go through replies, now only I could come online. & here replies are too early than expected.

Comment: Guys plz see my post starting with "@Megharaj! as you used" for my further query...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the output in an array, you will have to allocate an array of appropriate size. There is just no way around that.

But you don't need to do that if you use `popen`. You get a `FILE *` handle and can just read the output in small parts and process it on the go.

> from where I'll filter the data and show it on output console screen.

How do you do that? With the shell or in C? If in C, then you read the output of the `system`ed command just like you would read your txt file. The only difference is that you need to close it with `pclose` instead of `fclose`, so there are only advantages to doing it with a text file.

If in shell, then you can start the program you use with another call to `popen`, this time in a `"w"` (write) direction and write the output of one pipe as input to the other. However, in this case you could have just called a shell with an anonymous pipe in the first place. ;-)

***Edit:***

Your own answer makes clear that your requirements are quite different from what you think they are. There is no way to read the output of `reg export` back via a pipe and `popen` if it insists on writing to a file.

What you can try is to write a file to your temp folder; you should be allowed to create files there, otherwise Windows will not work correctly. Just specify something like "%TEMP%\reg.out" as file and read your data back from there.

If that doesn't work, you are out of luck with `reg export`. But you can use some Windows API function for querying the registry directly. Here is a [starting point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alternatively, you might want to look into the possibility of employing PowerShell. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885505/powershell-how-to-use-standard-output-in-place-of-filename) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary file using some API from Windows, and store your data in it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363875(v=vs.85).aspx

There is a C++ example in the link, you should be able to adapt it to your case.